# Unable to move keys between keychains

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm trying to set up a build machine and want to move private keys from a dev machine to the build machine.

I've exported the keys from the dev machine's keychain but when I try to install them on the build machine I keep getting an error saying:

"An error has occurred. Unable to import an item. The contents of they item cannot be retrieved".

I've tried re-exporting the keys, tried just clicking on them on the build machine, tried dragging them into keychain access, tried adding them to the login keychain, the system keychain, tried with a public key, tried with a private key, its always the same error message every time.

(The keychain is unlocked).

Any suggestions how I can find out what the problem is, and rectify it?

Comment: Private keys and public keys get exported to different kinds of files (with different extensions).  What are the extensions of the files that you get when you export your private & public keys?

Comment: The public got exported as .pem and the private as .p12

Comment: also, how are you transferring the files?  a file server or a USB stick or?

Comment: Originally the keys were pushed to and pulled from a git repository, then after failing to install them I tried exporting them again but that time transferred them using a UBS stick.

Comment: I wonder if your USB stick is formatted for Macintosh (e.g. journaled, extended, etc.) or Windows (e.g. FAT32; which is what I suspect it's formatted for)

Comment: Its formatted for Mac. However it also didn't work via git. I've nothing else to try so I'll try email as a transfer medium